# Local administrator unique to machine when joining Azure AD with Intune

Tags: windows-10, azure-active-directory, intune

I set up automatic Windows 10 machines enrollment to Azure AD. Machines join Azure AD without a problem and users can log in. Users do not have local admin permissions for the machine by default. But I need every machine to have a local admin (one user for one machine, not for all machines).

Now, I do this with Windows Device Configuration and I do specify local admin (not Azure AD user, just a local machine user). When the machine is joined Intune policy is applied. When logged in, I see that user (local admin) in local users and its a member of Administrators group. But local log on is not allowed (and I have no idea how to enable it).

So can I set up Intune (or whatever) to have all Azure AD users as a standard users but also for every machine to have a local admin? Can't figure this out and can't find this case in the Microsoft docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can enrolled to Azure with users and then assign some Azure AD user to local admin. Here is the steps:
1. Login to the PC as the Azure AD user you want to be a local admin. This gets the GUID onto the PC.
2. Log out as that user and login as a local admin user.
3. Open a command prompt as Administrator and using the command line, add the user to the administrators group. As an example, if I had a user called alvipeo, the command would be "net localgroup administrators AzureAD\alvipeo /add" without the quotes.
4. Log back in as the user and they will be a local admin now.

Best regards,
Cici Wu

Comment: Log in with local user is disabled completely for some bizarre reason. So I can't figure that out